# Mysql não retorna valor do timediff

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde, estou montando um trigger no qual preciso retornar a diferença entre dois DATETIMEs. Estou tentando usar o código abaixo, porém o mySQL não retorna nada.
Se eu executo o Select diretamente ele retorna sem atribuir uma variável ao mesmo o mySQL retorna o tempo corretamente...
Como posso resolver este problema?

P.S.: Estou usando PHPmyAdmin com mySQL versão 5.7.22

```
SET @dh = "2018-11-23 00:00:00";
SET @tempo2 = (SELECT TIMEDIFF(@dh,now()));
```

Comment: Aqui pareceu funcionar: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qhUvN7eQBK4cFYBdg8xCdS/0. Consegue fazer um [mcve] reproduzindo o problema?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se meu cerebelo entendeu: voce quer pegar uma diferenca entre o tempo da prineira variavel e o valor gravado no campo mysql. Porem vem vazio.  Eh isso?

Comment: No final do trigger tento passar a variavel @tempo2 em um insert mas o mesmo aparece na tabela como zero...                                                           INSERT INTO tb_paradas values (NULL,@tempo2,@dh);

Comment: `SET @dh = "2018-11-28 00:00:00";
SET @tempo2 = (SELECT TIMEDIFF(@dh,now()));
select @tempo2;`

Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou, utilizo o mySql 5.7.19, quando imprime o @tempo2 o que acontece ?

Comment: Funciona direto no comando, porém usando uma trigger o resultado inserido na tabela é zero, como dito acima... Acabei fazendo diferente, via SP onde consegui o resultado que queria, porém ainda não tenho a reposta do porquê não funciona no trigger.